# onClick takes 1 second to show UI of the next activity

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

I have an activity called `Activity1`. In that I have an `onClick` event for a button view. My `onClick` function is,

```
personViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent m = new Intent(v.getContext(), PlaceActivity.class);
                m.putExtra("place_position","null");
                m.putExtra("parent_place_url_name","india");
                m.putExtra("parent_place_name","India");
                m.putExtra("parent_place_id","null");
                m.putExtra("parent_place_coverimg","null");
                m.putExtra("place_url_name", sacIndiaLevel1PlacesLists.get(i).place_url_name);
                m.putExtra("place_apiurl",sacIndiaLevel1PlacesLists.get(i).place_apiurl);
                m.putExtra("place_name",sacIndiaLevel1PlacesLists.get(i).place_name);
                m.putExtra("place_coverimage",sacIndiaLevel1PlacesLists.get(i).place_coverimage);
                m.putExtra("lastlevel","No");
                m.putExtra("place_totallastlevel_places_insidechildplaces",sacIndiaLevel1PlacesLists.get(i).place_totallastlevel_places_insidechildplaces);
                v.getContext().startActivity(m);
                  Toast.makeText(personViewHolder.itemView.getContext(), "end of onclick",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

After clicking it goes to `Activity2`. When I click the button, immediately it does show the next activity `Activity2`. It stalls at the screen of `Activity1` for a sec and then shows the UI of `Activity2`. How to know what is causing to stall at `Activity1`.

Comment: some heavy loading task inside? Or huge images in a view? something in that way....

Comment: If you show us your onClick and the onCreate, onStart and onResume methods (if available) of your Activity2 we could help you out.

Comment: I have image in appbarlayout, but i am using glide with a placeholder. other loading tasks of api i do from volley.

Comment: View my edited question with the code of onclick. My onclick is taking time. I came to know about it, when i added a toast text "end of onclick" at the end. When i click the toast text is not shown immediately. It shows with 1 sec delay. how to check the start time and end time between the passing the variables to intent.

Comment: From your code I can't say what is causing the delay. What I'd guess is that the arraylist (it is an arraylist, right?) lookup is somehow delaying it. There's 2 things you could try. 1) Comment out the list lookup part and see if performance improves. and 2) Lookup the correct object only once (`sacIndiaLevel1PlacesLists.get(i)`) store it in a temp variable and then call it's properties from the temp variable instead of looking up the object each time.

Answer (score 0):

I think u are using so much operations in UI thread. Try to create new thread and make some background task using it.